# Permission denied when trying to install Adobe Air

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to install Adobe air 2.60 on Sabayon Linux with 3.12 kernel.
When I tried to execute installer, I get "permision denied" error from execvp.

```
dzar@dzar Adobe/ $ ls -al
drwxrwxrwx  2 dzar dzar     4096 05-23 02:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 dzar dzar    12288 05-23 02:39 .. 
-rwxrwxrwx  1 dzar dzar 16127348 05-19 19:46 AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
dzar@dzar Adobe/ $ ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin 
execvp: Permission denied
```

Same situation have a place when I'm using root account.

Comment: You need to modify the folder permissions.  It appears that the owner of the folder is different from the user your actually using and the group permission does not allow writting to the folder.

Comment: I don't thing that's the case, I'm using user that is owner of the directory

Comment: Have you tried to sudo the command.

Comment: I've tried it with 777 on both file and directory. (And with root account)

Comment: Using root account/sudo doesn't change anything